# Getting dropdown value from template django

Tags: django, django-templates

I am facing an issue working with django ( using shopcart ). I want to add a select options field to change dynamically an item suscription in the cart, but I am not getting the value selected from the template.

In my template where I display the cart I have :

```
<form action="" method="GET">{%csrf_token%}
<select name="suscr" title="suscr">
<option value="" selected>Suscribe</option>
<option value="1" name="suscr" >Weekly</option>
<option value="2" name="suscr">Monthly</option>
</select>
</form>
```

I want to select an option and then, if I press 'Checkout' to have the cart updated.

Appart from that, I believe its missing a method modifying the item in cart.py.

Any ideas would help.

Thanks

The above form is inside a loop 
{% for item in cart %}

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "not getting the value selected from the template"? I assume you have some view that your form is submitting to, and that the action attribute is not actually blank? Is "suscr=<value>" not showing up in the url after the user submits?

Comment: As a side note, if the Subscribe option is just there to act as a title, you should not actually have it be part of the dropdown; use a label instead. If it is a meaningful option, then its value should not be blank.

Comment: I mean that its not retrieving the value. In my view I check for method GET

Answer (score 0):

What i propose you to do is not python-oriented but all javascript for the most part as, from the description, we assume that what you are dealing with is going all at the client-side.

As you are dealing with a shopping cart, what i'd do is **storing what the user is checking in a [sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage#sessionStorage)** so that the information would persist while the user navigates through your website even with multiple tabs. As the user might just be "walking around" you shopping website, there's no need to push things to the database without even knowing if the user wants that. Just remove the `form` and keep with the select, then you get what the user selected appending an attribute to select: `<select onchange=my_function(this.value)>...</select>` and then, inside `my_function`in a `script` change whatever you want to the page.

When the user enters the shopping cart page you show him what he selected so far getting the items from the `sessionStorage`and then, if he/she confirms that wants to buy, then submit a form to the server-side, update the database and proccess that as your workflow states.

**tl;dr**: store the options in *sessionStorage*, just post to the server at the end.
For help on the server-side update your question with more info about the `cart.py`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am already storing the cart in a session before the user proceeds to checkout. But, when I show the user the cart (in session ) I give them the option to select a "suscription type" for each item. I want then to update that session with the suscription choice from the select option. ( with no need of an extra button, direct from the select option ). Hope I could clarify my issue.

Comment: So, the problem is getting the value from the `<select>` and then sending it to a view that will add it to the session? If that is the problem it is partially solved with the answer as the `onchange`is triggered everytime that the user selects something. It would just need to define a view to handle a request with the data and update the session that comes with the request. Tell me if i misunderstood it again (and sorry for typos and grammar errors)

Comment: Yes I think you are right. But can I change a value in the session with a script in the template ? or theres a way of passing the selected value to the view through the 'onchange' ?

Comment: Just pass the value to a view. For doing that asynchronously i think something like [this](http://paste2.org/MIKV2UWH) should be sufficient. it is the only way to get the session object that is particular to that user and change it. You're able to do that by POST or GET, you decide